# Create tab on click in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, project

I am making a program as a personal project and part of it requires me to click a button and then a new tab is created, in which on the same button click labels will be created and displayed in the tab.

How would i create a tab on click in vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about Windows Forms:

On a `TabControl`, there is a [TabPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpages.aspx) property which is a collection of all tab pages on this control. This collection has an `Add` method to add a new tab page.

Example:

```
Dim newTabPage As New TabPage()
'Add controls to this new tab page here

myTabControl.TabPages.Add(newTabPage)
```